# Compare what files when update the service reference

Tags: visual-studio, wcf

Say I updated one WCF service, so in the client side I can view the changes by click view history on the service reference node.

My question is if I wonder what are changed between the changesets, what files should I select?

I think that I can select `reference.cs` to make a comparison. But is it right? There are many other files such as xsd files.

Answer (score 0):

Try to right-click the service reference and view it in object browser. You could see the generated proxy class.
If you want to compare the difference between the updated service reference and the old one, you could generate client proxy class via SVCUtil.exe tool and then check all generated files.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dotnet/netframework-3.5/aa347733(v=vs.90)
such as,

> Svcutil.exe http://localhost:1300/mex /Directory:D:

[image]

Comment: I guess that you misunderstood my question. Say I updated the service reference, I know that there are differences. Can I just compare reference.cs only or I have to compare all files? The reason is there are too many xsd files,; and I don't want to diff them one by one. In other words, if the service reference has been changed, does the `reference.cs` definitely change as well?

Comment: The service reference contain the service contract,datacontract and client proxy class, it definitely changed from before.